# Session variable giving error. worked before

Tags: php, session, indexing, undefined

I seem to be getting an error in my php file. It was working earlier but now it just doesnt seem to work

not sure why its giving me this error

The Session "login_user" is created in a login page which is then called in the catalogue page. and **for some weird reason it seems to trigger whenever i click on the "empty cart" link**

however if i remove the above line the error seems to go away. But i need that line for the user to log out.

Any idea whats wrong with the code

this is the the code where the session "login_user" is made:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
include_once('config.php');

$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['pass'])) {
$error = "Please complete both fields";
}
else
{
// Define $username and $password
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=md5($_POST['pass']);
// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$user = stripslashes($user);
$pass = stripslashes($pass);
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $user);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $pass);
// SQL query to fetch information of registered users and finds user match.
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users where Username='$user' AND Password='$pass'");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$user; // Initializing Session
header("location: home.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
} else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
mysqli_close($mysqli); // Closing mysqlinection
}
}
?>
```

the error i get is:Notice: Undefined index: login_user in C:\wamp\www\catalogue.php on line 28

and Line 28 is:

```
Welcome, <?=$_SESSION['login_user'];?>! <br> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

line 28 is surrounded by normal html:

```
<div id="content">
    <!-- This is the actual menu --> 
    <ul id="darkmenu">
          <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="catalogue.php">Catalogue</a></li>
          <li><a href="search.php">Search</a></li>
          <li><a href= "view_cart.php">Cart</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Orders</a></li>
    </ul>   

    <div id = "welcome" >
    Welcome, <?=$_SESSION['login_user'];?>! <br> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Where is your 'empty cart' link?

Comment: Are short open tags enabled? If not do `<?php echo $_SESSION['login_user'];?>` instead of `<?=$_SESSION['login_user'];?>` - Most likely the issue. What do you think Sam? @JayBlanchard

Comment: Heres the link to the whole of the catalogue.php file where empty cart is called around line 94: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxmZzO?editors=100

Comment: @Fred-ii- if short open tags are not enabled then the line 28 doesn't contain any PHP code. And no PHP code means no notices.

Comment: @Fred-ii- <?php echo $_SESSION['login_user'];?> didnt seem to solve the problem

Comment: @resontant81 I hope you **don't** destroy the session in `cart_update.php?emptycart=1`.

Comment: True. Then if that second piece of code is in a different file, then they probably haven't started the session. @axiac nor are they using `isset()`. Could be a mix of things.

Comment: Wondering if the file that `Welcome, <?=$_SESSION['login_user'];?>! <br> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>` is in, is even a `.php` extension.

Comment: *Obligatory* **Warning** You are vulnerable to SQL Injection. This is 2015, there is no reason not to use [prepared statements with MySQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to avoid **SQL Injection**.

Comment: Your query may have failed then. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i get the following error after adding the error reporting 
`( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SESSION' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\catalogue.php on line 30`

Comment: When PHP says there's an error on a certain line number, it doesn't always mean it's on THAT line. Something else is causing this and you'll need to post the full code that's associated with that. Check out http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/common-php-errors-solution_t for possible help. So, you'll need to show full code for me to help any further.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwypRQ?editors=100 thats the full code from catalogue.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- could be that the error is to do with this file also? cart_update.php 
emptycart is used in this file
link to code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azRWvp?editors=100

I've just noticed that if i remove the line of code which says welcome then i dont receive any errors and im able to empty the cart :/

Comment: No, I doubt highly the problem is there neither. I would start looking into your config.php file. That is where I think the issue starts; something I thought of from the *get-go*.

Comment: My config.php file is very small: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JomNXJ?editors=100

Comment: I have no idea and have spent a lot of time trying to find the problem but was unable to reproduce the problem, which is why I deleted my answer. I wish you well, good luck. I'd of liked to have given you the solution that was required in order to close the question. *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

The notice message `Notice: Undefined index: login_user in C:\wamp\www\catalogue.php on line 28` just means, that you should initialize the variable before, e.g.

```
$user = $_SESSION['login_user'];
```

To me it sounds like you forgot an session_start(); on top of an php-file.

Comment: Still the same error :/ i have session_start(); right at the top of the file.

Comment: @resontant81: Check if the variable is NULL too, I'd recommend

$user = empty($_SESSION['login_user']) ? $_SESSION['login_user'] : "null";
If it still won't work, please provide more code of the calatalogue.php